# Is System.getProperty("user.home") equivalent to Paths.get("~").absolutePath?

Tags: java, nio, java.nio.file

By equivalence, i mean logical equivalence, not the String comparison.
E.g. if I do `Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("file.txt", System.getProperty("user.home"))` and `Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("~").resolve(Paths.get("file.txt")))`, will I get the same file on Windows and other systems?

Comment: No. Only shells understand `~`. It isn't a valid path component in the file system.

Comment: "Home" on Windows is highly subjective.  The duplicate should enlighten you on that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course no. Tilde character has special meaning in shell. It points to `HOME` variable. In Java `~` is like any other file name. In addition in Windows you cannot use `~` as home directory equivalent.